# jQuery actions are causing the page to scroll to the top

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of `li`s:

```
<li id="rules-button">Rules</li>
<li id="download-button">Download WK</li>
<li id="gallery-button">Gallery</li>
```

And they have jQuery actions associated that show and hide `div`s:

```
var rulesButton = $( '#rules-button'),
downloadButton = $( '#download-button' ),
galleryButton = $( '#gallery-button' );
```

...

```
rulesButton.on("click", function(){
    home.fadeOut(300);
    gallery.fadeOut(300);
    contact.fadeOut(300);
    about.fadeOut(300);
    download.fadeOut(300);
    rules.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
downloadButton.on("click", function(){
    home.fadeOut(300);
    gallery.fadeOut(300);
    contact.fadeOut(300);
    about.fadeOut(300);
    rules.fadeOut(300);
    download.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
galleryButton.on("click", function(){
    home.fadeOut(300);
    download.fadeOut(300);
    contact.fadeOut(300);
    about.fadeOut(300);
    rules.fadeOut(300);
    gallery.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
```

Whenever I click on them, they scroll back to the top of the page before showing the other `div`.  Is this a common problem with a common solution?  Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like this code is doing that. Are there no `a` tags?

Comment: yeah, it's not this code. Must be happening somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that since I was making the `div`s disappear, there was no element to fill the space.  I simply gave my container `div` a min-height attribute.